# Strange exception in creating Android Contacts Group

Tags: android, android-contacts

looking at my google analytics page lately, I have seen that sometimes an exception is raised and I have no clue to resolve it as I have not been able to reproduce it. The idea of the code is to check if a custom contacts group exists and if not, create it. The code is the following:

```
public static long ensureSampleGroupExists(Context context, Account account)    {
    Log.v(TAG, "ensureSampleGroupExists");

    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

    // Lookup the sample group
    long groupId = 0;
    final Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Groups.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Groups._ID },
            Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME + "=? AND " + Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE
                    + "=? AND " + Groups.TITLE + "=?", new String[] {
                    account.name, account.type, SAMPLE_GROUP_NAME }, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                groupId = cursor.getLong(0);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    if (groupId == 0) {
        // Sample group doesn't exist yet, so create it
        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        contentValues.put(Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        contentValues.put(Groups.TITLE, SAMPLE_GROUP_NAME);
        contentValues.put(Groups.GROUP_IS_READ_ONLY, true);

        final Uri newGroupUri = resolver.insert(Groups.CONTENT_URI,
                contentValues); //<-- NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION IN SOME DEVICES (or at least 1 :P)
        groupId = ContentUris.parseId(newGroupUri);
    }
    return groupId;
}
```

I can see in the google analytics webpage the following exception --

`NullPointerException (@ContactManager:ensureSampleGroupExists:95) {SyncAdapterThread-1}`

Not sure if the problem is the `ContentResolver` but when checked it was not `null` (neither was null the context) so i am a little bit confused...

Unfortunately there is no bug report so I have no stack trace:(, does somebody have any clue about what could be happening? Any help would be highly appreciated

Thank you

**EDIT**

I managed to get the full stacktrace thanks to GA 4, check it out

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1478)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185) 
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137) 
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:468) 
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1190) 
at com.smm.epctrackerapp.sqlite.ContactManager.ensureSampleGroupExists(ContactManager.java:96) 
at com.smm.epctrackerapp.adapter.ContactSyncAdapter.onPerformSync(ContactSyncAdapter.java:72)
at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)
```

Comment: add a **catch** clause before **finally**. and try printing the stacktrace. then you'ill get the exception log

Comment: But the exception raises after the **try / finally** block, are you suggesting to wrap all the code in a **try / catch** block?

Comment: ya..wrap your last if block in a **try/catch** block.

Comment: are you certain that **account** is not null

Comment: I have followed your suggestions but as I cannot reproduce the problem I am not sure if it has been fixed, I will try to make my GA v4 to report the whole stack trace for future problems.

Comment: @Boss I managed to get the full stacktrace look at my edited answer :)

Comment: try **final ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();** in onCreate and use it in your function.